# FastAPI Endpoint Pagination with Generator

Tags: python, rest, pagination, fastapi

I converted path operation to a generator as below. To get a generator when call is made to endpoint and to loop over pages of data instead of getting all data at once, but what I observe actually I still get data at once. Now instead of getting a list of dictionaries, I just get a two dimensional list in which there are multiple lists whose length is equal to my page size and their each element is also dictionaries. Why generator behaved in this way and what should I use to implement pagination? Does storing data in a global variable and returning a chunk of it for each call to endpoint make sense?

```
@overlaps_router.get("/query")
def query_overlaps(query: str,
                testdrive_id_list: List[str] = Query(None),
                predecessor: bool = False,
                db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        data_to_paginate = []
        
        if not data_to_paginate:
            logger.info("No data to paginate. Data will be calculated!")
            results = crud.query_overlaps(query, db, testdrive_id_list)
            logger.info(f"First row of results: {results[0]}")
            if predecessor:
                result_with_predecessor = calculate_predecessor(results)
                data_to_paginate = result_with_predecessor
            else:
                data_to_paginate = process_result(results)

        logger.info(f"Length of data to paginate:{len(data_to_paginate)}")
        limit = environment.env_variables["PAGINATION_OFFSET"]
        page = []
        for datum in data_to_paginate:
            if len(page) < limit:
                page.append(datum)
            else:
                yield page
                page = []
        yield page
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(f"Exception: {str(e)}")
```

Endpoint is called some other place:

```
# This one returns three lists in another list because
# data size is 2125 records and PAGINATION_OFFSET env
# variable is 1000, so it still returns all data at once
# in three different lists.
result_text = requests.get(request_string, params=params).text
print(json.loads(result_text))
```

Comment: The `yield` will just end the view function right there - it will not be kept around for later HTTP requests. Storing data in a global variable will just make it impossible to handle multiple users, since you'll now have requests overwriting previous data that was stored if another user makes a request in between. `offset` is usually used to indicate the starting point inside the data set, while `hits` (or `rows`, `row_count` or similar) the number of entries to return. You could probably just do `return data_to_paginate[offset:offset+hits]`? That way you won't manually copy entries

Comment: Thanks. What about handling multiple users?

Comment: That will depend on the data you're actually using and how it's relevant / adjusted for each user. Usually you have some sort of backend storage where the data is located (a database, a key/value-store, etc.). You can generate the data and then stuff it in a data store to be paginated later, and expire it as necessary (any rdbms such as mysql/postgres/etc. can handle that, or you can use something like Redis to store data with a time to live so that it gets automagically removed after a day or two and you can regenerate it). Attach it to a unique key/user id if the data is user specific

Comment: I understand, thank you. Nice directions.